# How can i run shell script at boot (start up)

Tags: linux, boot, rhel5, startup

How can i run shell script every time my system boot ( start up ) in linux (RHEL 5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo /path/to/script.sh >> /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 3):

As dyasny said, you can add the script call to your `/etc/rc.local`.

Another (cleaner) way would be to write an init script for it, place it in `/etc/init.d/yourservice` and add rc links to it (I don't remember which command does that on RHEL5) so that it gets started in the right position during boot and stopped during halt (if necessary).

Comment: the command is chkconfig I guess :)

Comment: Yep thanks. I'm more of a `update-rc.d` guy ;-)

Comment: But update-rc.d doesn't accept arbitrary scripts. They have to be "LSB-compliant" or whatever.

Comment: @user38334: You wish, really...