# How run on the boot .sh script

Tags: linux, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i run shell script at boot (start up)](https://serverfault.com/questions/109104/how-can-i-run-shell-script-at-boot-start-up)

I have .sh script to run my game server with mono.
I need run this command on the boot

```
sh script.sh start
```

How do it?

Answer (score 1):

Put it into `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

sh /path/to/script.sh start
```

or in a cron job with a special activation parameter:

```
crontab -e
@reboot /path/to/script.sh start
```

Comment: I believe it is meant to be /etc/rc.local.